# Load Dialog and keep prev page in background?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

Loading a dialog will make disappear the prev page in order to show the dialog. Is there a way to leave prev page and load dialog over it?

That way I can give dialog some transparency background, or even no background!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new overlay panels in jquery mobile 1.2 alpha will accomplish what you're wanting. I'd wait til they work out the bugs though.

See here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/popup-panels.html